# Name for the property $f(g(x)) = h(f(x))$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am aware of the concept of equivariance, when two maps $f, g : X \rightarrow X$ satisfy

$f(g(x)) = g(f(x))$

for all $x \in X$. Does there exist a name for the (seeminlgy) similar property of maps $f, g, h : X \rightarrow X$ satisfying

$f(g(x)) = h(f(x))$?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Conjugate_maps

Comment: Actually, you may want $Y=X$ for these properties (or at least $Y\subseteq X$, but why add unneeded complexity)

Comment: Thanks! And good point, $X = Y$ seems like a reasonable assumption for this question. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little cleaner to generalize to the case of two objects $X$ and $Y$ and maps

$$f : X \to Y, g : X \to X, h : Y \to Y.$$

(This is as general as we can get and still have an identity in the desired form.) Then I would say that $f$ [intertwines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivariant_map#Representation_theory) $g$ and $h$, or more precisely that $f$ intertwines the action of $g$ on $X$ and the action of $h$ on $Y$.

Abstractly, there's a category whose objects are pairs $(g, X)$ consisting of an object $X$ (in whatever underlying category) and an endomorphism $g : X \to X$ (a "discrete dynamical system") and whose morphisms are morphisms $f$ as above. It can be thought of as the category of actions of the free monoid $\mathbb{N}$ on one generator (here my $\mathbb{N}$ includes $0$).